# MySQL updating different fields based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I want the actual **field** updated to change depending on a condition. Existing examples I have come across only allow the value of the update to be changed, not the field. This is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE conversations 
CASE WHEN conv_author_id = $uid THEN SET conv_viewed_author = $d
ELSE SET conv_viewed_recipient = $d END 
WHERE conv_id = $id
```

However this gives me a syntax error.

How do I set the actual field updated to be conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE conversations
SET
  conv_viewed_author = IF(conv_author_id = $uid, $d, conv_viewed_author),
  conv_viewed_recipient = IF(conv_author_id = $uid, conv_viewed_recipient, $d)
WHERE
  conv_id = $id;
```

Comment: Never used mysql, that's quite less verbose than a case statement ;)

Comment: Thanks! Chose this answer for simplicity, but both answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do something like this:

```
UPDATE conversations
SET 
    conv_viewed_author = (
        CASE conv_author_id 
            WHEN $uid THEN $d 
            ELSE conv_viewed_author 
        END
    ),
    conv_viewed_recipient = (
        CASE conv_author_id 
            WHEN $uid THEN conv_viewed_recipient 
            ELSE $d 
        END
    )
WHERE conv_id = $id
```